# Kafka How to prevent losing data over brokers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using Kafka 0.10.2.0. I have 3 brokers and i am doing some failover tests. Sometimes when one of the kafka brokers is closed ungracefully, I am loosing data.
Kafka broker configuration :

```
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
num.partitions=50
min.insync.replicas=2
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
group.max.session.timeout.ms=10000
group.min.session.timeout.ms=1000
```

Consumer configuration :

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, getTopicName() + "group");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, getClientId());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 500);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 3000);
```

Producer Configuration:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, getClientId());
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 800);
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 800);
```

What can I do to stop losing data over kafka brokers?

Comment: Set producer config `acks=all`  See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Comment: I have already added acks all to producers.

Comment: With unclean leader election disabled, and acks=all you should not loose any data. If you can reliably reproduce this scenario, please report a potential bug to dev@kafka.apache.org (http://kafka.apache.org/contact) or open a Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a replication factor of 3 for your topic?

Some great advice from last years Kafka Summit https://www.slideshare.net/ConfluentInc/when-it-absolutely-positively-has-to-be-there-reliability-guarantees-in-kafka-gwen-shapira-jeff-holoman?from_m_app=ios

Video of the session is here https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-2016-ops-when-it-absolutely-positively-has-to-be-there/

Comment: Yes all topics have replication factor 3. I have already checked the slide. I am using autocommit false and I dont have any problems on committing the message. I am sure the producer is sending the message to the topics correctly. But after that when broker is down, I am losing data. It has not always been happening but when doing the tests like : start sending messages to kafka , close one of the brokers then open it again then close other broker ...  I am losing data on that cases.

Comment: How do you know the data is lost? If you consume messages from the beginning offset using console-consumer is the data no longer in the Kafka log? If you switch back to the original broker are the messages still there?

Comment: I am not starting the offset from beginning, I am using manual commit with commitSync.Strategy = earliest. I know data is lost because in the logs I can see  messages already delivered to brokers. So when I have messages on kafka topics and I started the kafka broker again , on consumer side when I call poll method I can see that some messages are being skipped . May be offset position was changed but why  or what should I do ?

Comment: Lost messages and skipped messages are two different things so it sounds like perhaps you are not losing messages (I.e. missing from the Kafka log). You are trying to understand why your consumer is skipping messages and not processing them all. Do you have a single consumer? How many partitions are there in you topic? When you call poll() how many messages are you receiving  in each poll? Are you calling commit after processing each message individually or after processing the entire batch?

Comment: I have single consumer for each topic. 3 topic . each of them has 1 partition. I am calling poll method with poll(100) so I am not sure how many  messages received on each poll but in flight request per connection is 1 . I am calling commit after processing each messages individually,Hmm it is the case. Thanks. Looks like I am receiving more than 1 message but using commitSync after each individual message. If I prevent reading more than 1 message each time, I will not loose any data. How can I do this ? using fetch.size will not solve my problem. data size is changing ..

Comment: Use max.poll.records to control how many records are consumed. The max in flight requests  parameter is just for producers.